# MVC. Itextsharp write pdf to response

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2, itext

I am generating pdf using itexsharp.
I am creating MemoryStream,  then when i am trying t write MemoryStream bytes  in to response but no luck. When i am executing this code in my controller the pdf not coming in response. Memory stream is populaitng correctly i can see this in debugger, but for some reason this number of butes not coming in response.

Here is my code:

```
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"; 
        ...
        using (Stream inputPdfStream = new FileStream(pdfFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        using (Stream outputPdfStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inputPdfStream);
            PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, outputPdfStream);
            ....

            //try one
            outputPdfStream.WriteTo(HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream); // NOT POPULATING Response
            //try two
            HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(outputPdfStream.ToArray()); // NOT POPULATING Response Too

            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }
```

May be some one have any ideas?

Comment: are you getting anything at all in the response?

Comment: Yes, a few bytes, but not bytes of my pdf

Comment: I would have posted a simpler example, not including the inputPdfStream which is another pdf file so it leads to confusion. Just the output MemoryStream as the stream for the PdfWriter instance, a document.open(), some document.Add(..) and a document.close(). Then the question reduces to "I want to send in the response the pdf contained in the output MemoryStream. How to?..."

Answer (score 3):

Could you not use

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf")
Response.WriteFile(pdfFilePath)
Response.End()
```

Comment: In the original question he reads a pdf as input from a FileStream and generates another pdf as output in a MemoryStream, that pdf in the MemoryStream is what needs to be send in the response content. Why the "Response.WriteFile(pdfFilePath)" then?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `FileContentResult Controller.File(byte[] content, string contentType)` method:

```
public ActionResult GeneratePDF()
{
    var outputStream = new MemoryStream(); // This will hold the pdf you want to send in the response

    /*
     * ... code here to create the pdf in the outputStrem
     */

    return File(outputStream.ToArray(), "application/pdf");
}
```

Source: [Building PDFs in Asp.Net MVC 2](http://blog.tacticalnuclearstrike.com/2010/09/building-pdfs-in-asp-net-mvc-2/).

Answer (score 0):

Probably the memorystream is still set at the position after the last written byte. It will write all bytes from the current position (which is none). If you do a `outputPdfStream.Seek(0)` it will set the position back to the first byte, and will write the contents of the whole stream to the response output.

Anyway, like Dean says, you should just use the `Reponse.WriteFile` method.